# html/css page displayed not in full size in mobile version

Tags: html, css

I'am working on `HTML/CSS` project, Project contains 3 files:

```
index.html
contacts.html
style.css
```

Two web pages and one `CSS` file, project almost done.

```
index.html// fully adaptive
```

`contacts.html` adaptive for laptops, tablets, but when I use:

```
@media(max-width: 667px){
}
```

`contacts.html` displayed not in full size:
http://prntscr.com/umgkzw

here is link to web page:
https://imbabot.000webhostapp.com/contacts.html

How I should fixed it?

Comment: remove **padding-left and padding-right** @ mobile view 480px in `.contacts { padding-left: 180px; padding-right:80px;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your CSS seems to cause the problem:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px)
@media (max-width: 667px)
@media (max-width: 1024px) 
.contacts {
    padding-left: 180px;
    padding-right: 180px;
}
```

A padding is set to your `.contacts` class. Try removing this padding, as it resizes your `div` element.

Also remove the `width: 450px;` from your `.FeedBack`class.

Change:

```
.FeedBack {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    color: lightgray;
}
```

to:

```
.FeedBack {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Also your message-block is to big. This is causing the problem. Remove the witdh from `.FeedBack` class and it will work :)

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this however you may have to fix few things according to the media query after applying this code

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
body,html {
   max-width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
 }
}
```